# ADO.NET ExecuteScalar() not throwing exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, executescalar

I am testing ExecuteScalar(), in particular, how it deals with thrown errors in SPs.
When executing a SP with this shape:

```
throw 50001, '', 1;
select 1;
```

the exception is raised by ADO.NET (expected behavior), but, if I execute a SP with this shape:

```
select 1;
throw 50001, '', 1;
```

the exception is not raised (unexpected behavior), I get the selected value (1 in this case).
I imagine this is related with the way Sql Server streams its data back to ADO.NET, but I do not know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the exception you are throwing is not being detected is because the ExecuteScalar() method grabs the first result set returned from the command or stored procedure and discards any other results.

This means when the exception is raised after a result is returned you will never see it with the ExecuteScalar() method, as the method has stopped looking for result sets from the database server and is essentially ignoring any other information sent back.  You can see this if you returned 2 values (i.e. Select 1; Select 2; Throw;) as the second would never be seen.

If you are concerned about this behaviour, or you might have expected to receive multiple result sets from the stored procedure, then you should use ExecuteReader() to get a Data Reader and then use the Reader Object's NextResult() method to iterate through all the result sets returned, then you will see the exception being sent back to your program.

Comment: Thank you! I will update my code based on your explanation.

Comment: @Mauricio - No problem - can you vote it as an answer if it is working for you.