# Catch an error from try/catch in SQL Server at client side (C# Winform) using ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I am developing windows application in C# with SQL Server as backend. I have to display the error message generated in stored procedure, which is handled in try catch block, to the application. It is working fine if we use `ExecuteNonQuery()`. The stored procedure will return one ID so I am using `ExecuteScalar()` and that error message from the catch block is not displaying.

For `ExecuteScalar` also the error will display if we remove the try catch block.

It will not display in client side.

```
begin
begin try
    select 1/0
    select 10
end try
begin catch
    raiserror (' Some Error Message', 16, 10)
end catch
end
```

It will display in client side.

```
begin
    select 1/0
    raiserror (' Some Error Message', 16, 10)
    select 10
end
```

Kindly provide a solution.

Comment: For a start you should be using `throw` not `raiserror`

Comment: And what's the purpose of using `try/catch` if you want to return the error to the client? It doesn't appear to accomplish anything.

Comment: @DaleK, Same with throw also. Master and child table insertion is happening in same procedure. So if any error occurs in any transaction it has to be rollbacked. And the  try/Catch is using for that rollback purpose.

Comment: does this solve your doubt https://stackoverflow.com/a/42809670/6582884 ?

Comment: @AmalPs, In my point of view , in the first case, that  'select 10' command won't execute, so raiserror will be the first result. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Rakesh in your first query Divide by zero error encountered. this would be the error

Comment: @AmalPs Moving the Select command after the try/catch block solved the issue.  DaleK , AmalPs , Thank you for the guidance and your valuable time.

Comment: @AmalPs , yes in the first query it will jump to catch without executing the 'Select 10' command. Right ? Then the first result will be the error message I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ensure SqlExceptions are detected, all result sets must be consumed by the client. `ExecuteScalar()` returns only the first row/column of the result but does not consume the remainder of the results, so the exception is not raised by the client API.

This example code will raise the error by avoiding `ExecuteScalar()` and consuming all results:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlBatchText, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
        if (reader.Read())
            {
                scalarIntResult = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }
        while (reader.Read()) { }; //consume remainder of first result
        while (reader.NextResult()) { }; //consume subsequent results
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Below are common cases where undetected SqlExceptions may occur. If a defensive programming technique like the above is not employed, it is important to code T-SQL to ensure these scenarios do not occur.

1. An error is caught by T-SQL TRY/CATCH while executing a row-returning statement.
2. An error occurs after a row-returning statement successfully executes.
3. An error occurs after a row count message is returned (depending on client API).

See [this article](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I was trying to manage it by ExecuteScalar() itself. That's why I asked. Now I have to go for ExecuteReader() for proper handling. Thank you.

Comment: @Rakesh, please mark this as the answer to your question to help others with the same question find the answer.